# Bit operations on an arbitrarily large bit-array or number

Tags: c++, data-structures, bit-manipulation

I have a very simple question: In C++, is there an in-built or straightforward way to group a large (~1000) number of bits (or bools) in a single label such that the inbuilt bit operators function as they do for fundamentals?

e.g. for a `long` you might write:

```
unsigned long maximum = ~0;
```

or one might use:

```
somenum>>;
```

Is there an analogous way to do this for a block of memory of arbitrary size?

If not, what are some good alternatives ? I have thought of bit `<vectors>`, a C `union`, etc., but these all seem to require handwritten routines for the various bit operations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep!  It's called **[`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)** and does just that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do believe it does. I had hoped for such an obvious answer !

Answer (score 0):

Also, [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) might be useful depending on the requirements. I wish it was standard instead of the hack that `std::vector<bool>` is